# Convert SQL Time using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, sql

I want to convert MySQL Time data type using PHP and Javascript. I know it can be done using FORMAT_TIME of MySql, but I would like to do the same with php. The Time format is hh:mm:ss by default and I would like to convert it to hh:mm.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php

Comment: Do You use a Datetime Field? or only Date? or a Timestamp?

Comment: Where does the javascript fit in?

Answer (score 1):

Just feed the date into the following function(s):

```
<?php echo date("h:i", strtotime($date)); ?>
```

Comment: thanks, I like this solution! Can be integrated easily where I display the output

Answer (score 1):

```
//any date is ok, we care only about the hours and minutes
// $your_date is what comes from db in format hh:mm:ss
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01 '.$your_date);
echo $date->format('H:i');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create a DateTime object and then use format("h:i") to get the desired output